# How to force the indentation of the first paragraph on org-mode export?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have a simple `Org` file with this:

```
#+STARTUP: showall align
#+OPTIONS: todo:nil tasks:all tags:nil
#+AUTHOR: Manoel Vilela
#+TITLE: Super title @@latex:\\@@ Title to be write
#+DATE: <2017-08-24 Thu 03:02>

* Description

Description about what this file is talking about.
This is a paragraph. But the start is not indented


This is another paragraph, but this is ok.
```

Which I got this on pdf export.
[image]

But I expect that first paragraph is indented too. How can makes this directly?

Comment: (I'm glad you found something that does what you want.) It's usually better not to indent the first paragraph. Indentation should separate a paragraph from the previous one, and in this case there *is* no previous paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like an org-mode-flavour duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading

The top answer from that question is to use the standard LaTeX package "indentfirst". The org-mode equivalent answer is to put the following at the top of your buffer:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{indentfirst}
```

Works for me in my quick test.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't find this before. Just a quick question: is there a simple way to use multiple LaTeX commands on #+LATEX_HEADER? Because I already use one to setup my native language (which is not english).

Comment: Glad to help. You can have as many separate #+LaTeX_HEADER lines as you like -- you don't need to try to combine them and they're all taken into account. I've lots! Once you've run the exporter you can always look at the generated .tex file and you'll see that your block of setup is effectively copied near the front.

Comment: Yes! Nice. Your tip worked fine. I defined as a separated #+LATEX_HEADER.

Comment: Do you want to mark this answer as correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. Marked.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I added that in my config such that I don't have to add the `#+LATEX_HEADER` every time: `(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "indentfirst"))`